# I can't hear music, but can hear all system sounds

Tags: settings, music

I use external sound card, and can hear all system sounds, but when I play any song from player ("melody", "music" or "Spotifi"), I can't hear anithing.
When I use headphones without external sound card - all works correctly.
I tried to use mixers, `alsa force-reload` and other.

I use Elementary Os Juno

```
apt list --installed | grep "audio"

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libaudio2/bionic,now 1.9.4-6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libopenshot-audio6/bionic,now 0.1.5+dfsg1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libpcaudio0/bionic,now 1.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libwebrtc-audio-processing1/bionic,now 0.3-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
pulseaudio/bionic-updates,now 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth/bionic-updates,now 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
pulseaudio-utils/bionic-updates,now 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins/bionic,now 0.8.8-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of elementary OS are you using? Can you please update the question with the output of this command, `apt list --installed | grep "audio"`?

Comment: @Hasan Question updated

Answer (score 1):

Try installing pavucontrol by executing `sudo apt install pavucontrol`on terminal. It gives you a little more control over selecting inputs and outputs and is a bit more robust than the default mixer.

Comment: You can check on pavucontrol > Output which Port do you use and eventually set the external sound card